# Changing a list (passed as a function parameter) changes the list with the same name in the previous function call

Tags: python

Recently a friend of mine asked me to explain a strange behavior in a piece of code originally intended to count permutations using recursion. There were many improvements that could be made to the code, which I noted, but these seemed to not have any real impact.

I simplified the code down to the following, which reproduces only the problem, and not the permutations.

```
def foo(bar, lst):
  if(bar == 1):
    lst.append(0)
    return
  print(lst)
  foo(1, lst)
  print(lst)
foo(2, [])
```

The output is

```
[]
[0]
```

I tried lst += [0] or deleting lst after appending 0, but these did not help. Doing lst2 = lst.copy() followed by lst2.append(0) gave the expected result of two []s, however. I am confused as to why appending 0 (or any value) to lst where bar == 1 would have an effect on the lst where bar == 2. I do not consider myself a total beginner to Python, and I usually can determine the behavior of local variables. This has baffled me though. An explanation would be really appreciated.

In case you want the original code, though I don't think it'll give much more info, here it is:

```
A = 0
A2 = 0
NN = 3

def P(N, C):
  global A
  Temp = [X for X in range(1, NN + 1) if X not in C]
  if(N == 1):
    C.append(None)
    A += 1
    return
  for e in Temp:
    C.append(e)
    P(N - 1, C)
    del C[-1]

def P2(N, C):
  global A2
  Temp = [X for X in range(1, NN + 1) if X not in C]
  if(N == 1):
    A2 += 1
    return
  for e in Temp:
    C.append(e)
    P2(N - 1, C)
    del C[-1]

P(NN, [])
P2(NN, [])
print(A, A2, sep = " ")
print(A == A2)
```

Comment: There is only one 'lst'.  You create it via '[]' in the last line of your code.  The only condition under which something gets added to this one list is when "bar == 1", at which point "0" is appended.  This occurs in the recursive call to the function, between your two print statements.  It isn't clear to me why you would expect a different result.

Comment: I just wanna point out that to work with permutations it's better to use a python C library such as [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for efficiency reasons

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: There is only one 'lst'.  You create it via '[]' in the last line of your code.  The only condition under which something gets added to this one list is when "bar == 1", at which point "0" is appended.  This occurs in the recursive call to the function, between your two print statements. I guess you're thinking that lists in Python are passed by value.  They are not.  In your code, 'lst' always contains a reference to the one and only list you create at the end of the code.  The list is never copied.   As @quamrana says, check out [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've checked out Ned Batchelder, and it is very useful. @umberto, yes, itertools's permutations is better, and it is what I usually use, this was more of a python exercise. One more question, del(lst) after appending 0 to lst removes lst in the scope of bar=1 while lst still exists when bar=2. Since there is only one lst as I have now learned, does this mean deletion of a variable only removes the variable from its current scope, and that the same variable may still exist externally?